# How make row size of seaborn clustermap equal?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using Python 3.6.7

Code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0, 1, size=(50,4)))
g=sns.clustermap(matrix, col_cluster=False, linewidths=0.1, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Heights of the first and the last rows are clearly smaller than the rest. How to make all of them equal?

Comment: This problem is solved in more recent matplotlib/seaborn versions.

Comment: @JohanC Yes it does